# Getting an SQS message state in boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS producer and lots of consumers. It would be very helpful to know if the producer can tell if a *particular message* has been deleted by a consumer or not. Is there a way of doing this? I'm currently using boto 2.6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, SQS does not provide any mechanism to be notified when a message is deleted.  So, I think if you want to know when messages are deleted, you will have to keep track of that separately by keeping a database of message ids and having consumers tell you the message id of any messages they have deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't track an message in a Queue. Depending on your goal you could try the following things:

**Monitoring**

Write the results of a job to a logfile, and maybe use something like [logstash](http://logstash.net/) with [Kibana](http://kibana.org/). If you get creative you might even fire things straight into something like ElasticSearch or SimpleDB.

**Callback**

The receivers could fire any kind of "callback" to the processor or any other process updating a certain message state in for example a database or a cache.

You have to keep in mind that this means that while you scale up your receivers, your processor has to scale up as well. Also keep an eye on your indexes, make sure your status update "write" is fast.